# how to include a model in an API which is connected to another model by foreign key in djangorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework for building an API

I have 2 models which are Projects and Comments:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    header_image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg")
    demo = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)


class Comemnts(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want the project API to show the comments also but not as a different API how can I do that

here is my serializer:

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"
```

and here are my views:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def getProjects(request):
    project = models.Project.objects.all()
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProject(request, pk):
    project = models.Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

how can I show the comments also in the project's object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use nested serializers. you can find some examples here:
[Nested Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)